# How can I avoid to show values in scientific notation in R?

Tags: r

I have this code in R to tabulate a frequency table:

```
TablaFrecs = function(x,k,A,p){
  options(scipen=999)
  L = min(x)-p/2+A*(0:k)
  x_cut = cut(x, breaks = L, right=FALSE)
  intervals = levels(x_cut)
  mc = (L[1]+L[2])/2+A*(0:(k-1))
  Fr.abs = as.vector(table(x_cut)) 
  Fr.rel = round(Fr.abs/length(x),4) 
  Fr.cum.abs = cumsum(Fr.abs) 
  Fr.cum.rel = cumsum(Fr.rel)
  tabla = data.frame(intervals, mc, Fr.abs, Fr.cum.abs, Fr.rel, Fr.cum.rel)
  tabla
}
```

but it shows the intervals in scientific notation
[image]

The ej 9 it's this:
[image]
I'm usingthe OFF.COURSE Variable

I've tried options(scipen=999) and format(scientific = F) but is doesn´t solves it.

PD: I also want to make an hist() of my TablaFrecs function, how can I do it?

Comment: Could you supply an example of  the function call with usual parameter values?

Comment: TablaFrecs(Ej9$OFF.COURSE, k= 27, A = 3646296, p= 0.1) where k is size of interval, A is size of interval and p is for precision

Comment: Jaffet León, that helps, but since we don't have `Ej9`, we're really no better off.

Comment: I posted it above

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: (Since the only data we're using is `Ej9$OFF.COURSE`, you could give us *just that column* instead of plenty of data we don't need to address this problem. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `mapply` and `format` to create the labels:

```
TablaFrecs = function(x,k,A,p){
  options(scipen=999)
  L = min(x)-p/2+A*(0:k)
  labels = mapply(function(x,y){paste0("[",format(x),",",format(y),")")},L[-length(L)],L[-1])
  x_cut = cut(x,
              breaks = L ,
              labels = labels,
                right=FALSE)
  intervals = levels(x_cut)
  mc = (L[1]+L[2])/2+A*(0:(k-1))
  Fr.abs = as.vector(table(x_cut)) 
  Fr.rel = round(Fr.abs/length(x),4) 
  Fr.cum.abs = cumsum(Fr.abs) 
  Fr.cum.rel = cumsum(Fr.rel)
  tabla = data.frame(intervals, mc, Fr.abs, Fr.cum.abs, Fr.rel, Fr.cum.rel)
  tabla
}

TablaFrecs(1e6, k= 27, A = 3646296, p= 0.1)

             intervals       mc Fr.abs Fr.cum.abs Fr.rel Fr.cum.rel
1   [999999.9,4646296)  2823148      1          1      1          1
2    [4646296,8292592)  6469444      0          1      0          1
3   [8292592,11938888) 10115740      0          1      0          1
...
```